# JSon string return null using DeserializeObject in C# Console Application

Tags: c#, json, console-application

I am following this [sample code](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeObject.htm) to deserialize json string. It works fine, however, when I try the same with my Json I got null. Below is my source code in C# console application to deserialize the json string. Please help me to figure out what I am missing in order to deserialize.

```
public class Account
    {
        public string AgentTradeAssociation { get; set; }
        public string AccountNoAgentTradeAssociation { get; set; }
        public string Event { get; set; }
        public string AgentPoint { get; set; }
        public string BillTo { get; set; }
    }
    public class Program
    {   
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string json = @"[{'F1':'AgentTradeAssociation','F2':'AccountNoAgentTradeAssociation','F3':'Event','F4':'AgentPoint','F5':'BillTo'},{'F1':'This be Corporation - TW','F2':'ACC-XYZ-R21RLF','F3':'XYZ Manufacturing 2018','F4':'Old (1)','F5':'This be Corp'}]";

            Account[] account = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Account[]>(json);

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is not a valid JSON string.

Comment: when having JSON deserialization issues please check string for validity, e.g. here https://jsonlint.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, [your JSON is invalid](https://jsonlint.com/).

That fact aside, based on your definition of `Account` the JSON for an `Account` object should look like this:

```
{
    "AgentTradeAssociation": "string",
    "AccountNoAgentTradeAssociation": "string",
    "Event": "string",
    "AgentPoint": "string",
    "BillTo": "string"
}
```

You are passing in this schema based on the JSON array:

```
{
  "F1": "AgentTradeAssociation",
  "F2": "NoAgentTradeAssociation",
   ....
}
```

Which is not the `Account` type you defined in C#.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Actually, I am reading an Excel sheet, converting into DataTable and then serialize into Json using JavaScriptSerializer.Serialize. So from DataTable, that is what I am retrieving. Can you please explain if I can format Json as par the standard way?

Comment: @MohsinA. Why are you reading in a spreadsheet into a datatable and then serializing it into JSON to then deserialize it into a model..? By the time you actually get an `Account` any performance gains you'd get by having a statically typed data object are lost by all the serialization/deserialization and reserialization.. Just use the `DataTable` you are getting from the spreadsheet, it makes no sense at all to do all of that work to get a POCO (Plain Old C# Object), if it's truly necessary to have a POCO, you can just read the `DataTable` into a new POCO instance of `Account`

Comment: Actually, I were supposed to enhance the feature and in the meantime I came accross with this mess. However, your point is valid to use DataTable instead of Serialize-Deserialise and vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your JSON, you have the name of properties and there value backwards, e.g. `F1` has value `AgentTradeAssociation`. To deserialize that JSON you would need classes that look something like this:

```
public class Class1
{
    public string F1 { get; set; }
    public string F2 { get; set; }
    public string F3 { get; set; }
    public string F4 { get; set; }
    public string F5 { get; set; }
}
```